# Erro ao usar JSON com datatable

Tags: ajax, datatable

Estou tentando implementar meu `json` utilizando a ferramenta `datatable`, segue meu `json`:

```
[
{"Nome":"Felipe","Data":null,"Tipo":"Normal","RG":"123456798"},
{"Nome":"Felipe2","Data":null,"Tipo":"Normal","RG":"123456798"},
{"Nome":"Felipe3","Data":null,"Tipo":"Normal","RG":"123456798"}
]"
```

fix um exemplo no **JSFIDDLE** url: 
    https://jsfiddle.net/o3b8tf32/

Após isso, gostaria de saber se há alguma possibilidade de deixar o cabeçalho dinâmico, ou seja,  os `<th></th>` do `<thead>`

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue o JsFiddle com a resposta: https://jsfiddle.net/o3b8tf32/1/

Faltou o `<tr>` no `<thead>` na declaração da tabela:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>Tipo</th>
    <th>RG</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

E também corrigir o construtor da DataTable

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataSet = [ {  "Nome": "Felipe",  "Data": "null",  "Tipo": "Normal",  "RG": "123456798"}, {  "Nome": "Felipe2", "Data": "null", "Tipo": "Normal", "RG": "123456798"}, { "Nome": "Felipe3", "Data": "null", "Tipo": "Normal", "RG": "123456798"}];

  $('.table').DataTable({  
     data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { data: "Nome" },
            { data: "Data" },
            { data: "Tipo" },
            { data: "RG" }
        ] 
    });
});
```

Segue a documentação do [DataTables.net com datasource JavaScript](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html).

Segue também um exemplo com colunas dinâmicas: https://jsfiddle.net/o3b8tf32/6/

Comment: Obrigado @Thiago , amigo, tem como deixar o cabeçalho do `<thead>` dinâmico, tipow, o nome da propriedade ja pegar direto pelo ajax

Comment: Para constar, segue o fiddler com a geracao dinamica de coluna https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/o3b8tf32/5/

Comment: Legal, @RBoschini. Fiz um update com filtro das colunas: https://jsfiddle.net/o3b8tf32/6/