# Como fazer a coluna do DataTable dinâmica

Tags: datatable

recentemente eu fiz uma pergunta:

[Erro ao usar JSON com datatable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106600/erro-ao-usar-json-com-datatable)

O que estou precisando é parecido, só que preciso deixar o nome da coluna dinâmico, ou seja, teria algum jeito de pegar a propriedade do meu `json` e deixar ela setada como o nome da minha coluna, obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aproveitei seu [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/o3b8tf32/5/) da outra questão e fiz uma alteração com base nessa pergunta nova.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var json = '[ {  "Nome": "Felipe",  "Data": "null",  "Tipo": "Normal",  "RG": "123456798"}, {  "Nome": "Felipe2", "Data": "null", "Tipo": "Normal", "RG": "123456798"}, { "Nome": "Felipe3", "Data": "null", "Tipo": "Normal", "RG": "123456798"}]';

  var column_names = []; //Array com confi das colunas
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json); //Parse no obj json, facilita o manuseio

  //Verifica se tem registro, para nao caga tudo
  if(jsonObj.length>0){

    //Monta array de colunas
      $.each(Object.keys(jsonObj[0]),function(idx,obj){
      column_names.push({"sTitle": obj, "mData":obj});
    });

    $('.table').DataTable({
      "aaData": jsonObj,
      "aoColumns":column_names
    });

  }

});
```

Veja se te ajuda

Atualizei sua pergunta com a geracao dinamica de colunas.

Comment: Oi @RBoscini, obrigado por responder, mas não era o que eu preciso, tem alguma maneira de deixar o nome da coluna dinamico, tipow, so declarava o ajax, ele pegava o nome da propriedade e setar na coluna?

Comment: Claro que tem, mas preciso saber oq vc quer fazer, cada coluna vem o nome junto com o json? vai vir na ordem correta, vai vir em cada linha, como vc vai enviar esse dado via ajax? mande a estrutura que montamos juntos isso

Comment: Vamos pegar esse json como exemplo: `{ "Nome": "Felipe3", "Data": "null", "Tipo": "Normal", "RG": "123456798"}` minha tabela automaticamente teria que ficar com as seguintes colunas: "Nome, Data, Tipo, RG". ai os dados consequentemente com a sua respectiva propriedade, entendeu?

** vai vir na ordem correta, vai vir em cada linha, como vc vai enviar esse dado via ajax? ** R: vai vir na ordem correta, cada linha é cada objeto, não vou enviar ajax, so receber

Comment: alterei o fiddler, da uma olhada.

Comment: Opa @RBoschini, quase la, so que ela ta sendo preenchida

Comment: Atualizei o fiddler, pq me deu -1 ?

Comment: @RBoscihini, cara, n sei kkkk eu cliquei pra cima

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33825/discussion-between-furlan-and-rboschini).